# empty a control Array

Tags: javascript

Isn't there a way to emptyAll my control Array, i've tried doing it with a for loop :

```
console.log("primitif value : " + this.parameters.length);
      for (var index = 0; index < this.parameters.length; index++) {
          this.parameters.removeAt(this.parameters.length- index);
            console.log("seconde value :" + this.parameters.length);
      }
```

It's removing just the last value, i want to completely remove all elements, i can't neither do it like :

```
this.parameters = [];
```

Is there a way to do it ??

Comment: Try `this.parameters.length = 0;`. You can't remove items in a for loop that uses that array's length as its loop exit control.

Comment: i've tried it too, it does not work, it still contains controls .....

Comment: After setting this.parameters to [] or setting its length to zero, do a console.log on it. What does it show for this.parameters in the console? Something else must be resetting your array.

Comment: What about this.parameters = null;
this.parameters = [];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a cloned array of the parameters. Where you want to delete from the array, delete from the cloned one. Then call the cloned length. After the for loop set the parameters to the cloned.

```
console.log("primitif value : " + this.parameters.length);
    var clone = this.parameters;
    for (var index = 0; index < this.parameters.length; index++) {
        clone.removeAt(clone.length- index);
        console.log("seconde value :" + clone.length);
    }
    this.parameters = clone;
```

Using this solution means that if you need to manipulate anything in the parameters array or if an async method is going to try use one of these indexes they are still available until after the for loop.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
for (var index = this.parameters.length - 1; index >= 0; index--) {
      this.parameters.removeAt(index);
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `index >= 0`, in order to remove the first element? And `index = this.parameters.length - 1`?

Comment: Yea, my bad. But this should help her.

Comment: Or this solution:
`for (var index = array.length; index > -1; index--) {
      array.splice(index, 1);
  }`